# Is there a thing in Vuex that work the same as mapDispatchToProps in Redux?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I was trying to do things like `this.updateData()` instead of `this.$store.dispatch()` in a child component, where the `updateData` is a function inherits from its parent component. Anyone have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: I think what you want is to put a prop in the child component that is bound to a method in the parent component, could that be it?

Comment: Can you clarify a little for us not antiquated with Redux. From what I inferred from you question you want to trigger parent function from child component? I will write down an example of a way to accomplish this. If I'm off then just ignore my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So to update data of parent comp. from child component in Vue we can utilize [event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events) bus:

Parent:

```
<template>
  Hi Blake...
  <child-component @trigger="updateData()"></child-component>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {},
    methods: {
      updateData: function() {
        // this will be triggered from child
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child ( child-component ):

```
<template>
  <button @click="$emit('trigger')">Trigger Parent Function</button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {}
  }
</script>
```

Now this only triggers parent function but you can also send data with event that will be received by parent. This is just Vue without Vuex. If I'm wrong and you're not looking for this maybe you want to use Vuex mapActions which can be used to import all Vuex actions you need in your component and use them as `this.vuexAction` instead of `this.$store.dispatch('vuexAction')`.

I hope I helped. Good luck.